# How to use fetch_many / execute_many in sqlx?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

In my sample program I'm trying to do the following:

```rust
use futures::StreamExt;
use sqlx::Connection;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut conn = sqlx::MySqlConnection::connect("mysql://user:pass@localhost/db")
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let mut s = sqlx::query(concat!(
        "UPDATE foo SET bar=false WHERE id=34;",
        "UPDATE foo SET bar=true WHERE id=43;"
    ))
    .execute_many(&mut conn)
    .await;

    while let Some(k) = s.next().await {
        println!("{k:?}");
    }
}
```

But MySQL complains with `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE` error. So the question is how one is supposed to pass multiple queries so that they are properly recognized. Needless to say I am aware that I can run each query individually but I'd like to stack them up all together for performance reasons (server network latency).

Comment: Turn on [query logging](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/general-query-log/) and find out how the DB actually receives the statements.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold, there are no entries for such multiple queries. Single queries show up as expected.

Answer (score 2):

According to [a recent Github issue](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/2557), this approach won't work:

> The `.fetch_many()` and `.execute_many()` methods on `Query`, `QueryAs` and `Map` should probably be deprecated because they don't work with the prepared statement protocol of most databases. In fact, multi-statement query strings are generally expressly forbidden in this case because they are the core element in SQL injection attacks, which prepared statements were created to counter.

SQLx also lacks support for query pipelining, so as far as I can tell there is no way of sending multiple statements at once.